# Changing the signature of a function from def parsing_tasks(dag_def : DagClass), where DagClass is a class to just dag_def, what is the impact?

Tags: python, function, class

I have have the following class and global function:

```
class DagDefinition: 
    ....
    dag_def...


def parsing_tasks(dag_def: DagDefinition): 
    ....
```

I don't quite understand the syntax of the argument of the function `dag_def: DagDefinition`. I have come across something similar where colons are used in the arguments of a function, something like `variable:str`, which tells us that the type of `variable` is a string I believe.

Is there more to it?

The reason I ask is that in my codebase I would like to move the `parsing_tasks` function above the `DagDefinition` class, but to do that I would need to change the signature of the function to be just:

```
def parsing_tasks(dag_def):
```

But when I do this and call on `parsing_tasks` some odd things happen where previously I pass one argument to the function and that it is fine by now it says 2 position arguments are passed to it when it expects 1.

It is quite hard to reproduce the example as there is a lot of code around it, but if necessary I can try to replicate it.

The question first and foremost is whether or not changing the signature of the function above has any impact on how the function is called.

Comment: Those are called "type hints".  They have zero impact on a script's execution.  They are only used by IDEs and other syntax analysis tools that look for typing problems.  Some people believe in them religiously.  Some people don't.  Are you sure that's not a class method that needs a `self` argument?

Comment: As they mentioned before, they are simply "type hints". Personally, I think it's a good decision to include them. However, if you decide to include them keep in mind that FastAPI uses these "type hints" to do data validation (actually it does it through Pydantic), so if the type hints are not met on a FastAPI endpoint you will get a ValidationError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called *type hints* and removing them from your function signature will have no impact at all. As [the official documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

There are also many libraries that take advantage of them, like [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/).